# Unable to use kickthemout

Tags: wireless

I am new to Linux and want to use Kickthemout to block internet usage to some home devices while sitting in my room, but I cannot make it work as shown in a YouTube video, how can I overcome this and where can I overcome the fault I can overcome?

[image: terminal]

Comment: You've not provided any Ubuntu product & release details; the starting point for providing help.  Why not tell us, instead of making us guess?  Alternatively you could try `python3 kickthemout.py`  (`python3` is installed by default on most Ubuntu products)

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 0):

According to the [kickthemout](https://github.com/k4m4/kickthemout/blob/master/kickthemout.py) GitHub page kickthemout.py is compatible with Python 3+. To launch KickThemOut from the terminal change directories using `cd` to the directory that contains kickthemout.py and run the following command:

```
sudo python3 kickthemout.py
```

Installation:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install nmap
git clone https://github.com/k4m4/kickthemout.git
cd kickthemout/
sudo -H pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Note that KickThemOut's requirements must be installed by pip3 for compatibility with Python 3.

From a security standpoint running KickThemOut in a virtual machine would provide an additional layer of isolation between the tool and your host system. In the event of any unexpected behavior, security risks, or potential issues with the tool, the impact can be confined to the virtual environment. In many cases this is what pipx from the default Ubuntu repositories is designed to do, but it wouldn't give much of an advantage with KickThemOut because KickThemOut is supposed to be run with administrative privileges using the `sudo python3 kickthemout.py` command.